# Accounts-UI hangs on loading during login

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using some `accounts-*` packages in my application. At very first times it was working without any problem. Then I commited it to [github](https://github.com/rsercano/meteor-reminder) and pulled from somewhere else.

Afterwards, I couldn't login with any `accounts-*` package, including **facebook**, **password**, **github**, **google** etc.

*Note that, I've reseted my mongodb. Also successfuly configured all application informations for each service, and I dont have **autopublish** and **insecure** packages*

I thought I would have issues with publications and subscriptions. But it was working before my github push...

Some debug information:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook()
undefined
Meteor.logout()
undefined
Meteor.loggingIn()
true // it's always true
```

And it hangs for every service's (including **passwords**) **sign-in** request like:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks !

**Update:** I realized my **reactivity** is gone. Whenever I change a template (.html files) it doesn't refresh the browser... But if I open a new meteor project, all **reactivity** is working..

I suspect these issues are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error after hours...

I was trying to show some database entries according to the date every second. There was a code part as below in one of my **template's** **js**.

```
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    Session.set('alertNotes', Meteor.call('alertNotes'));
}, 1000);
```

Then I removed this and typed a helper as following code part, afterwards everything worked, including **sign-in** and **hot code push**...

```
    alertNotes: function () {
        return Notes.find({seen: {$ne: true}, date: {$lte: Session.get('time')}});
    },
```